# how to simulate a joystick

Tags: drivers, input, joystick

i'm trying to simulate a joystick so variable to joystick output
but i don't really find any information about how to make a virtual joystick
a came out at these api docs
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/joystick-api.txt
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/joydev/index.html
but i don't really understand them that well

Comment: What do you actually mean *trying to simulate a joystick* ?

Comment: I want to send a variable to a js0 file so that a game can see my variable as a joystick